# Trying to style every button in the footer to have a white color

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to style every button in the footer to have a white color. I really need to understand this

```css
footer button.mdc-icon-button {
  color: white;
  margin: 0.5em;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<footer> <button id='btn-address' class='mdc-icon-button material-icons'>home</button> <button id='btn phone' class='mdc-icon-button material-icons'>phone</button> <button id='btn-birthdate' class='mdc-icon-button material-icons'>today</button> </footer>
```

Comment: When you say `white color` do you mean a white background color then? Or do you want the text to be white?

Comment: Not background, the button color.

Comment: Nnamani, are you satisfied with my answer? Let me know if you need something else.

Comment: Thanks 
I actually do, I'm supposed to fetch an api
 
 const getAUserProfile = () => {
        const api = 'https://randomuser.me/api/';
          fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/')
          .then(resonse=> response.json())
        // make API call here

and destructure it with this functions

const displayBirthdate = () => {
      }
      const displayPhone = () => {
      }
      const displayAddress = () => {
        }
I don't know where to start

Comment: @NnamaniUgochukwu I'm afraid I can't help you there. If my answer to your question about styling the button is acceptable, you can click the check mark to accept and this will raise both our reputations. Also, you should make a new post for a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Background controls the color of your button and color controls the color of your button's text. I changed the body's background to grey so that the buttons would show up better.

```
body {
    background: grey;
}
button {
  background: white;
  color: black;
  margin: 0.5em;
  border: black;
}
```